# How to set envs into process.env with nginx and vuejs app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nginx

I'm trying to add envs to the `process.env` for my .JS files in NGINX, it's the first time I'm using it.

However, I've tried everything I found on the internet and nothing works.

My nginx.config

```
# env VUE_APP_API_URL3;
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
    fastcgi_param VUE_APP_API_URL 'teste';
    # set VUE_APP_API_URL1 'teste';
    sub_filter 'VUE_APP_API_URL2' 'teste';
    # set_by_lua VUE_APP_API_URL3 'teste'
}
```

What is commented is what I tried and it didn't work (it broke the build).

My auth.js

```
console.log(process.env)
```

Does someone know what I need to do ?

I need to do this because I need to get the ENV VALUE from the build tool (eg. docker)

One specific how-to-do

Comment: how does changing nginx.config affect the vue build process?

Comment: @JaromandaX With nodejs, I build (in react for example), the args/envs that I pass in the dockerfile reflect in the app in react.

I want to know if there is a way to do something similar